# Symfony 4.1 set DateType to european format

Tags: symfony, date, symfony4

I am currently working on a form using the Symfony form builder but I am experiencing some issues with changing the date format.

I created a DateType extension to override the default for all the fields, this is my code:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'placeholder' => ['year' => 'Jaar', 'month' => 'Maand', 'day' => 'Dag',],
            'years' => range(1920, 2019),
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        )
    );
}
```

As you can see in the format option I tried to change the default format to 'dd-MM-yyyy' without success. (Default is yyyy-MM-dd)

This doesn't change the actual format and just displays 2 "-" on the front-end. [image: As seen here]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Symfony documentation uses the:

```
    'widget' => 'single_text',
```

But this would mean a lot of changes in the front-end code.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of single_text widget is yyyy-MM-dd, but you can override it by passing the format as a string.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
$builder->add('date_created', DateType::class, [
'widget' => 'single_text',
'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
]);
```

Source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already stated this in my original question. This would mean a lot of changes in the front-end code. Is there no other way around this?